# jQuery slider does not work

Tags: jquery

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/status.css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
#demo-frame > div.demo { padding: 10px !important; };
    </style>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 37,
        min: 20,
        max: 700,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
        }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "value" ) );
});
</script>



   <div class="demo">

   <p>
<label for="amount">Maximum price:</label>
<input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;"        
     />
   </p>

   <div id="slider-range-min"></div>

   </div><!-- End demo -->



   <div class="demo-description">
   <p>Fix the minimum value of the range slider so that the user can only select a  
    maximum.  Set the <code>range</code> option to "min."</p>
   </div><!-- End demo-description -->
```

I am trying to use jQuery slider, http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#rangemin

I downloaded a file into my local machine.

The slider does not appear in the browser.

Any thoughts?

Comment: did you change the src of script and src files?
"js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your CSS, if you don't include the styles from:

http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

The slider will not show up. You can take the CSS elements in there, and configure them to your own.

Without CSS:

[image]

With CSS:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to all be correct per the example.  I would ensure that your include statements are correct for the location of the jquery files.